# "Translating" strings in bash with a call parameter? With the following python script

Tags: python, bash

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import argparse

vokaler = "aouåeiyäöAOUÅEIYÄÖ"
konsonanter = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZ"

def viskspraket(text):
    """Removes all vowels from the sentence"""
    return "".join([x if x not in vokaler else "" for x in text])

def rovarspraket(text):
    """Consonants are doubled and "o" is put inbetween them"""
    return "".join([x + "o" + x if x in konsonanter else x for x in text])

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-r", help="rovarspraket", action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("-v", help="viskspraket", action="store_true")
args = parser.parse_args()
textFromTerminal = input()

print(textFromTerminal)

if args.r:
    print(rovarspraket(textFromTerminal))

elif args.v:
    print(viskspraket(textFromTerminal))
```

In my assignment one part of the exercise is to execute this python script from the bash terminal with the following command:

```
$ echo "The landlubbers are trying to sink us with their canons." |./translation.py -r
```

Where "-r" is the call parameter I mentioned in the title. This part of the problem I have figured out and running it from bash works. 
But the next part of the problem is that I'm supposed to translate, the already translated string, with for example "viskspraket" without copying and pasting the translated string, from the bash terminal.

There are more functions in my translation.py file and I am supposed to be able to translate freely between all of the functions without copying and pasting, but I figured that two functions should be enough to illustrate the problem.

So, for example -r -v or something similar should first translate the string to "rovarspraket" and then taking that translated string and translating it again using "viskspraket".

Since there is five functions in total(only two are shown in the file right now), using something like:

```
parser.add_argument("-rv", help="rovarspraketToviskspraket", action="store_true")

elif args.rv:
    print(viskspraket(rovarspraket(textFromTerminal))
```

For all the possible translations wouldn't really be viable, since there is so many combinations. So my question is then:
How would I go about doing this? I'm very unexperienced with bash in general. I also apologize for the swedish function names, but I hope it's clear anyway.

Comment: pipe it again `echo '...' | ./translation.py -r | ./translation.py -v`

Comment: Oh wow, do I feel stupid right now. Thank you so much though.